# Casting size_t to allow more elements in a std::vector

Tags: c++

I need to store a huge number of elements in a `std::vector` (more that the 2^32-1 allowed by unsigned int) in 32 bits. As far as I know this quantity is limited by the `std::size_t` unsigned int type. May I change this `std::size_t` by casting to an `unsigned long`? Would it resolve the problem?

If that's not possible, suppose I compile in 64 bits. Would that solve the problem without any modification?

Comment: Changing to 64 bits will allow you to store those many items. But are you sure you require a vector in the first place i.e. does it have to be stored in *continuos* memory locations?

Comment: I think `std::size_t` is generally `unsigned long` type.

Comment: A `unsigned long` is normally (on most compilers, e.g msvc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx) the same as a `unsigned int`. A `unsigned long long` is actually the type your searching for

Comment: @Paranaix: On all 32-bit compilers and 64-bit Win32 compilers. On all other 64-bit compilers I've seen long is 64-bit. But that does not matter. `size_t` is defined to the same size as pointer no matter what primitive type it actually corresponds to.

Comment: 2^32 byte is 4 gigabytes, which is the maximum amount of memory you can access in a 32 bit system. So if your application is begin compiled as 32 bit, there is no way you can use more memory; Possibly you should seek for another architecture for your data structure.

Comment: Thank you, and Paranaix you're right , it's unsigned long long. Asha, I need to manage a lot of data both in 32 and 64 bits in an efficient way. Vectors are a standard and efficient way to manage the information as I want to.

Comment: @user1474074 Still, you cannot have a vector that has 4294967295 elements in a 32 bit Windows program. It is *impossible*, as a vector is stored in memory, and a 32 bit program can not even access 4294967295 _bytes_ of memory.(and if each of your elements are bigger than a byte, you can store even fewer of them..)

Comment: @JanHudec: That's not quite true.  C doesn't mandate that each pointer type be the same size.  There is nothing in the standard (to my knowledge) that states `size_t` is the size of a pointer (though it usually is the size of a machine word), only that it is a suitable type for representing string lengths and object sizes.

Comment: @nos: And in Windows you can only address 2GB by default anyway, 3GB with a couple of options turned on.

Comment: If you really do need to store >2Bn objects, then you should go straight to 64 bits anyway. You'll hit any number of other limits, not just the definition of `size_t` by sticking with 32 bits.

Comment: @EdS.: No, there is nothing in the standard that says `size_t` is the same size as pointer. But it does say that it must be able to hold size of any object that can be allocated in memory, which implies it in any model with linear addressing which all common platforms use these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size_t` is a type that can hold size of any allocable chunk of memory. It follows that you can't allocate more memory than what fits in your `size_t` and thus can't store more elements in any way.

Compiling in 64-bits will allow it, but realize that the array still needs to fit in memory. 2<sup>32</sup> is 4 billion, so you are going to go over 4 * sizeof(element) GiB of memory. More than 8 GiB of RAM is still rare, so that does not look reasonable.

I suggest replacing the vector with the one from [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/). It uses external storage, so your vector is not limited by amount of RAM. The library claims to handle terabytes of data easily.

(edit) Pedantic note: `size_t` needs to hold size of maximal single object, not necessarily size of all available memory. In segmented memory models it only needs to accommodate the offset when each object has to live in single segment, but with different segments more memory may be accessible. It is even possible to use it on x86 with PAE, the "long" memory model. However I've not seen anybody actually use it.

Comment: thak you, RAM is not a problem since it will run on machines (workstations typically) with more than 8 GB .I have to discard STXXL because I need the program to be fast in computation being data loaded in memory.

Comment: @LokiAstari, size_t is large enough to hold the maximal size of an object. With segmented memory, that usually was less than the maximum amount of memory. Most memory models for DOS had a 16 bits size_t while some of the memory models could access the whole 640K of RAM.

Comment: @user1474074: Ram **is** a problem. You say it will be running on machines with more than 8 GB. Since you don't give higher number, I don't think it is that much higher. But since your program needs more than `size_t` *entries*, it needs at least 8GB **times the size of each entry**. Do the machines have 128GiB memory?

Comment: @AProgrammer: You are right, but it's not relevant for any common 32-bit platform.

Comment: @JanHudec, your formulation suited me, I was reacting to Loki's one.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things to say.

**First**, about **the size of `std::size_t`** on 32-bit systems and 64-bit systems, respectively. This is what the standard says about `std::size_t` (§18.2/6,7):

> 6 The type `size_t` is an implementation-deﬁned unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size
>   in bytes of any object.
>
> 7 [ Note: It is recommended that implementations choose types for `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` whose integer
>   conversion ranks (4.13) are no greater than that of `signed long int` unless a larger size is necessary to
>   contain all the possible values. — end note ]

From this it follows that `std::size_t` will be *at least* 32 bits in size on a 32-bit system, and *at least* 64 bits on a 64-bit system. It could be larger, but that would obviously not make any sense.

**Second**, about the idea of **type casting**: For this to work, **even in theory**, you would have to cast (or rather: *redefine*) the type inside the implementation of `std::vector` itself, wherever it occurs.

**Third**, when you say you need this super-large vector "in 32 bits", does that mean you want to use it on a 32-bit system? In that case, as the others have pointed out already, what you want is impossible, because a 32-bit system simply doesn't have that much memory.

But, **fourth**, if what you want is to run your program on a 64-bit machine, and use only a 32-bit data type to refer to the *number* of elements, but possibly a 64-bit type to refer to the total size in bytes, then `std::size_t` is not relevant because that is used to refer to the total number of elements, and the index of individual elements, but not the size in bytes.

**Finally**, if you are on a 64-bit system and want to use something of extreme proportions that works like a `std::vector`, that is certainly possible. Systems with 32 GB, 64 GB, or even 1 TB of main memory are perhaps not extremely common, but definitely available.

**However**, to implement such a data type, it is **generally not a good idea** to simply allocate gigabytes of memory **in one contiguous block** (which is what a `std::vector` does), because of reasons like the following:

- Unless the total size of the vector is determined once and for all at initialization time, the vector will be resized, and quite likely re-allocated, possibly many times as you add elements. Re-allocating an extremely large vector can be a time-consuming operation. **[** I have added this item as an **edit** to my original answer. **]**
- The OS will have difficulties providing such a large portion of unfragmented memory, as other processes running in parallel require memory, too. [**Edit:** As correctly pointed out in the comments, this isn't really an issue on any standard OS in use today.]
- On very large servers you also have tens of CPUs and typically NUMA-type memory architectures, where it is clearly preferable to work with relatively smaller chunks of memory, and have multiple threads (possibly each running on a different core) access various chunks of the vector in parallel.

**Conclusions**

**A)** If you are on a 32-bit system and want to use a vector that large, using disk-based methods such as the one suggested by @JanHudec is the **only thing that is feasible**.

**B)** If you have access to a large 64-bit system with tens or hundreds of GB, you should look into an implementation that **divides the entire memory area into chunks**. Essentially something that works like a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`, where each nested vector represents one chunk. If all chunks are full, you append a new chunk, etc. It is straight-forward to implement an iterator type for this, too. Of course, if you want to optimize this further to take advantage of multi-threading and NUMA features, it will get increasingly complex, but that is unavoidable.

Comment: Re "The OS will have difficulties providing such a large portion of unfragemented memory, as other processes running in parallel require memory, too." - only the *virtual* memory has to be contiguous, so it doesn't matter how other processes are using *physical* memory, as long as there's enough available to map into our process. (Assuming paged virtual memory - there may be 64-bit OSes with other memory models, but I've not heard of any.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about allocating gigabytes in one continuous block.  The memory will be continuous within the process, but it will still be in virtual memory, and each page will be mapped independantly.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You are absolutely right. I have edited the post.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are, like Mike, absolutely right in pointing this out. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

A `vector` might be the wrong data structure for you. It requires storage in a single block of memory, which is limited by the size of `size_t`. This you can increase by compiling for 64 bit systems, but then you can't run on 32 bit systems which might be a requirement.

If you don't need `vector`'s particular characteristics (particularly O(1) lookup and contiguous memory layout), another structure such as a `std::list` might suit you, which has no size limits except what the computer can physically handle as it's a linked list instead of a conveniently-wrapped array.

Comment: -1: `std::list` is also limited by the size of `size_t`! Why? Because the total amount of memory is. You can't allocate more memory than what can be described by `size_t` no matter how hard you try (except in some segmented memory models nobody uses in practice).

Comment: To be more precise. The total amount of memory allocable is limited by size of pointer and on all common platforms, `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void *)`. The only case where that wouldn't hold is memory models with segment and offset where size_t only needs to hold size of the offset part. But while i386 has such memory model, it only has 32-bit page tables, so other segments can't be mapped to different 4GiB anyway making that memory model mostly useless (and thus nobody uses it).